# Node, Sqlite { stmt: Statement { stmt: undefined }, lastID: 0, changes: 1 }

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I'm working with node and the sqlite3 and sqlite npm packages.

I'm trying to run a prepared update statement which is failing. I have:

```
async function update_json_obj_into_table_by_PropertyId(db,tablename, obj, PropertyId) {

    const x = await db.run("UPDATE 'myData' SET StateCode = ? WHERE PropertyId = ? " ,obj.StateCode,PropertyId);
    console.log(x)
}
```

I'm calling it with:

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const sqlite = require('sqlite')

async function openDb() {

  const db = await sqlite.open({filename: './test.db',driver: sqlite3.Database})
  db.on("trace", (data) => { console.log(data); });
  console.log('connected!')
  return db;
}
```

followed by:

```
        if (StateCodeTable && StateCodeTable[0].type) {
            let json = { StateCode:StateCodeTable[0].type}
            const x =await update_json_obj_into_table_by_PropertyId(db,'myData', json, myR);
            console.log('inserted');
        } else {
            console.log('No insert');
        }
```

and I'm seeing in the console:

```
{ stmt: Statement { stmt: undefined }, lastID: 0, changes: 1 }
inserted
```

When I go back and chexk the table manually , I find that the updates have not been made. How can I fix this?

Edit,

I added:

```
db.on("trace", (data) => { console.log(data); });
```

Now in console:

UPDATE 'myData' SET StateCode = 'C1' WHERE PropertyId = 'R50155'
{ stmt: Statement { stmt: undefined }, lastID: 0, changes: 1 }
inserted

This looks right to me but and

```
SELECT * FROM 'myData' WHERE StateCode != 'NULL';
```

Is actually yielding the expected response when I test it manually - still not sure why it says undefined ..

Comment: Try enabling verbose mode and tracing SQL errors. Run these somewhere after you've created `db`: `sqlite3.verbose(); db.on("trace", (data) => { console.log(data); });`

Comment: please see edit